# In clutter can we remove all the actors from a table_layout?

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, clutter

I just need to clear all the actors added to the table_layout. So that i can add new actors . Is there any way i can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `clutter_container_foreach()`, e.g.:

```
  clutter_container_foreach (the_actor_using_the_layout_manager,
                             CLUTTER_CALLBACK (clutter_actor_destroy),
                             NULL);
```

or you can simply get the list of children using clutter_container_get_children(), and iterate the list.

if you want to remove the children without destroying them (e.g. you want to keep them around to reparent them) then you'll have to get the list of children, add a reference to them, and call `clutter_container_remove_actor()`.